How to get the current time inside a program? (not using Anchor)
Is there a way to get the current time as specified by the system running the node?
Any call like that panics:
let start = time::OffsetDateTime::now_utc();


You can interact with time using the Clock sysvar
use sysvar::clock;

let current_ts = clock::Clock::get()?.unix_timestamp;

This returns the UNIX timestamp in your program
more from rareskills -> https://www.rareskills.io/post/solana-clock#:~:text=timestamp%20in%20Solana,access%20the%20block%20timestamp%20Solana.&text=Somewhat%20confusingly%2C%20the%20type%20returned,deltas%20however%20can%20be%20negative.

Thanks! And a follow up question: is there a way to get this timestamp via RPC client? The idea is to include the timestamp inside the transaction data and check how much time it took for the instruction to be invoked.

I'm not sure on how you can do this. Might be best to create a new question for this.

If you fetch the Clock Sysvar account with getAccountInfo and use jsonParsed encoding you'll be able to view its data, including the unixTimestamp stored there.
